# php string sorting

Tags: php, string, sorting

I have one string in mysql database that contains characters and would like to do it next:

```
$string = "actor1 as aaa, actor2 as bbb, actor3 as ccc";

for (do a loop for 0 to length of the $string) {
   echo actor1
   echo aaa
}
```

So loop goes and print each time:

```
actor1
aaa

actor2
bbb

actor3
ccc
```

How to do that in PHP?

Comment: You better use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
$string = "actor1 as aaa, actor2 as bbb, actor3 as ccc";
$groups = explode(',', $string);

foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
  $items = explode(' as ', trim($group));
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    echo $item . '<br/>';
  }
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

or improoved without second loop:

```
foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
  list($actor, $role) = explode(' as ', trim($group))
  echo $actor . '<br/>';
  echo $role . '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(explode(",", $string) as $value) {
    $parts = explode(" as ", $value);
    echo trim($parts[0])."<br/>".trim($parts[1])."<br/>";        
}
```

Comment: Thanks..all..:) I try and use solution by periklis and is doing very nice...Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

NB: I've assumed you have a query but just haven't put in appropriate query strings, so I've added a typical mySQL example.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT actor1 as aaa, actor2 as bbb, actor3 as ccc FROM some_table");
$result = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numrows; $i++) {
  echo "actor1 <br>";
  echo $result->aaa . "<br>";
  echo "actor3 <br>";
  echo $result->bbb . "<br>";
  echo "actor3 <br>";
  echo $result->ccc . "<br>";
}
```